# Change image on hover in Wordpress portfolio list

Tags: css, wordpress, image, hover, portfolio

I'm using wordpress on my site and there is a visual composer's 'portfolio list' widget set on the homepage.

I have a masonry of images (links) which on click lead to the project's page.

The images featured on homepage are 'featured images' set on portfolio's project page. Is there a chance to make this images black and white on the homepage, and then colored on hover? So they are black-and-white while you visit the page and then colored once you hover over them!

The link is: http://svenharambasic.com

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

CSS has [Filter Effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) that you can use. Note that they're not entirely compatible with older browsers. But `filter: grayscale(100%)` on the image and `filter: grayscale(0%)` on hover will give you a simple effect like you're describing:

```css
.projects_holder img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: .25s all ease-out;
}

.projects_holder img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="projects_holder">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/220/280" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/250" />
</div>
```

There are some ways to get better browser support, if you're so inclined: https://gist.github.com/karlhorky/3478370

Comment: thanks for the quick answer; can you please tell me where should i put this code? In the additional css? And do I have to add it for the each image separately? 

Can you please give me an example on some of the homepage images if that's the case?

Comment: You can absolutely put it in the Additional CSS section. You may care to give the current [CSS Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) a once over to understand how it works. The code I gave you will apply to all images inside the div with the class `projects_holder`. It should effectively be a plug and play - but you _may_ need to change `img` to `article`.

Comment: great... ok so I added the first code and it makes everything grayscale, and that's what i wanted, however, it doesn't get colored once i hover over it.

what does the second code do exactly? what should i replace the kitten links with?

Comment: ok so i figured out, there was a problem because the widget's option overrides the css... there is an option 'hover animation' and there is no 'none', just default (which add colored box with text) and various others (zoom, split etc..., always with 'color' of choice)... is there a chance for this your css (grayscale: 0%) to have top priority?

Comment: Did you replace both instances of `img` with `article`? That's how I got it to work with DevTools open. Otherwise you can try adding `!important` to it.